# String replace to replace spaces and maintain dash

Tags: php, string, url, php-7, slug

I am trying to convert:

```
" Long Grain IRRI-6 White Rice "
```

to

```
" long_grain_irri_6_white_rice "
```

but it's returning this

```
" long_grain_irri-6_white_rice "
```

Here is the code:

```
public function phpslug($string){
    $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '_', strtolower($string));
    return $slug;
}
```

I want it to remove not only space between letters, I need it to remove also "-" this, so it can replace with "_".

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might remove `-` from your RegEx pattern:

```
function phpslug($string)
{
    $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '_', strtolower(trim($string)));
    return $slug;
}

var_dump(phpslug("  Long Grain IRRI-6 White Rice  "));
```

or you might simplify your RegEx pattern:

```
function phpslug($string)
{
    $slug = preg_replace('/[-\s]+/', '_', strtolower(trim($string)));
    return $slug;
}

var_dump(phpslug("  Long Grain IRRI-6 White Rice  "));
```

#### Output:

```
 string(28) "long_grain_irri_6_white_rice"
```

Comment: you have edited with new answer, this one not working, but the old answer to remove "-" from RegEx patern, that worked properly Thanks for that